# Bash scripting, gitlab post receive hook

Tags: linux, scripting, gitlab

would like to write a post receive hook which can return the current repository SSH address e.g *git@abc-git.anything.com:root/test-project.git*,
I have used this in post receive hook

```
var_ssh="$( git remote -v )" # get the current project ssh address
echo $var_ssh
```

But it shows nothing!

Comment: If you're wanting to install this on your gitlab server, I don't think the repo will have itself as a remote. You could try something like `var_ssh="$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)"` to construct the address you're looking for.

Comment: amazing....this is what i want thank you...

Comment: i have got this output ........git@abc-git.alpha.com:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root/test-project.git..... now i dont want /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/ how can i exclude it.

Comment: there's probably a better way to do this, but you could replace `$(pwd)` with `$(pwd | rev | cut -d/ -f2- | rev)`

Comment: sorry, `-f 1-2` not `-f2-`